# How to loop a string or convert a string to an array in JS? Or find a better solution to solve this

Tags: javascript

I am at  hour 14 of learning JavaScript, and doing some challenges.

The aim of this code is to find out how often a numbr occurs in the input.

The output is correct, if it occurs once it needs to be 0.
(Don't ask me why this is?! They want it like that and might have a reason. )

I don't think the solution is the most elegant. You can surely help me out here and tell me how to write it better. I had to add " " to the first and last position of the input and then - to convert it into an array - remove them again or it would create a new empty item to the array ( i think).
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
var input =" 12 34 56 78 12 34 1 87 12 "
var digits= input.trim();
    digits= digits.split(" ");
var arrayLength= digits.length;
var output ="";

for(var n=0; n<arrayLength; ++n){
    var outputD =-1;  
    var inputLocal = input;

    while (inputLocal.search(" " + digits[n] +" ") >= 0) {
        inputLocal = inputLocal.replace(" " +digits[n]+" ", ""); 
        ++outputD;
    } 
output += " " + outputD;
console.log(output);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a object as a map for counting, then use `map` to create the new array and then use `join`, like:

```
var input = ' 12 34 56 78 12 34 1 87 12 '
    arr = input.trim().split(' '),
    count = {}, result;

arr.forEach(function(item){
  if (typeof count[item] !== 'undefined') {
    count[item]++;
  } else {
    count[item] = 0; 
  }
});

result = arr.map(function(item){
  return count[item];
});

console.log(result.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(
  " 12 34 56 78 12 34 1 87 12 "

  .trim()
  .split(/\s+/)

  .reduce(function (collector, item) {

    if (item in collector) {
      ++collector[item]
    } else {
      collector[item] = 0; // 1
    }
    return collector;

  }, {})
);
```